# spring batch - job execution id?

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have a standalone testcase for spring batch to copy data form one table to another, however 
after each execution it increments the Job Execution and Job instance id by 1. Since i haven't scheduled any job thus how does it keep track of the previously executed job as it's incrementing the job instance by 1 every-time. Where is this persistent information stored?

Thanks!!
Tarun

I have got the answer to this question.

Comment: I got my answer, it's the jobrepository class that persists the data in the "batch_job_instance" table in the DB.

Comment: now that you have your answer, you should either add is as an answer and accept it or delete your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got my answer, it's the JobRepository class that persists the data in the "batch_job_instance" table in the DB